# Does a map update automatically if the original array is updated?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, count

I am creating an array in a for loop and using a map to keep track of the number of times I've used certain values (e.g. key: count; "AB": 2, "BC": 3). I've declared the empty array and created the map for that, outside the loop.

Inside the loop, I'm updating the array based on the value in the map ( `if (map.get(x) < 3) {array[i] = x}`).

I'm assuming the condition isn't working because I'm not updating the map, but is there a way to have the map update automatically as the array is updated?

```
var array = [];
var map = array.reduce((acc, e) => acc.set(e, (acc.get(e) || 0) + 1), new Map());

for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    if (map.get(random) < 3) {
    array[i] = random
    }

}
```

Comment: Automatic updates may be possible with [Proxies](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but it’s easier to define a simple function that will update both objects. I’m not quite sure how you expect your Map to be updated. Are you thinking of `const map = new Map([["AB", 2], ["BC", 3]]), array = [,, "AB", "BC"];`, where the map maps _value → index_ and the array maps _index → value_, and these two mappings should always be consistent, or something similar? How are these two objects linked?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hi! thanks for your advice- I've added some code to represent the problem. Let me know if it's unclear, I'm super new to JS.

Comment: At the moment you call `reduce`, `array` is empty, so you just get an empty `Map`. Once the `reduce` call returns, there is **no** enduring link between the array and the `Map`. Changes to one won't change the other. it's hard to help more specifically without knowing what you're trying to do. Also, note that `Math.random()` returns a *fractional* random number, so your `Math.random() * 10` will give you values like `2.9052941519059883`, `6.564470038647228`, and such. If you wanted integers 0-9, use `Math.round` on the result.

Comment: Side note: Since you're new to JS, let me warn you that `reduce` is primarily for Functional Programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions. You'll see it misused **a lot**, but in most cases (including your example above), a simple loop is clearer and less error-prone than `reduce`. `var map = new Map(); for (const e of array) { map.set(e, (acc.get(e) || 0) + 1); }` (Also: Use `let` or `const`, not `var`. `let` and `const` fix some issues `var` had.)

Comment: I'm trying to create an array with constraints (so max 2 of each integer for example) and I was thinking I could keep track of whether/how many times I used an integer in the array already. And thanks for the info about reduce, I'll probably alter my code based on that. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Laila - A `Map` makes sense for that! But you'll have to update it directly. Alternatively you could just build a `Map` with that info, and then build the array from the result, but I think that's more work.